# Change the size of random data generation on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running sort example on Hadoop using `RandomWriter` function. This particular function writes 10 gig (by default) of random data/host to DFS using Map/Reduce.

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter <out-dir>.
```

Can anyone please tell how can I change the size 10GB of `RandomWriter` function?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: I am naive in hadoop and java. I think I have only .jar file of hadoop-*-example.jar that contains the randomwriter class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example have some configurable parameters. These parameters are given to jar in a config file. To run use it as (suppling a config file)

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter <out-dir> [<configuration file>]
```

or run it with parameters as

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter 
 -Dtest.randomwrite.bytes_per_map=<value> 
 -Dtest.randomwriter.maps_per_host=<value> <out-dir> [<configuration file>]
```

For details about all configurable parameters see : https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/RandomWriter

Answer (score 1):

On Hadoop 2 (at least on the 2.7.2 version), the properties are now `mapreduce.randomwriter.mapsperhost` and `mapreduce.randomwriter.bytespermap`.

You can saw them on http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/RandomWriter.java?view=markup

So the correct answer on recent Hadoop 2 version is

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter 
 -Dmapreduce.randomwriter.bytespermap=<value> 
 -Dmapreduce.randomwriter.mapsperhost=<value> <out-dir> [<configuration file>]
```