# How to make 10G random text in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I want to make 10G size of random text by using hadoop.
But, when I use below command, the result is only 1.0G size random text.

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar randomwriter /user/root/random7
```

As I know, randomwriter example made 10G random text as a default.
How can I solve this problem?
The below result is output of command.

```
20/06/11 17:15:45 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
20/06/11 17:15:45 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Running 10 maps.
Job started: Thu Jun 11 17:15:45 KST 2020
20/06/11 17:15:45 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
20/06/11 17:15:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local203266267_0001
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local203266267_0001
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local203266267_0001_m_000000_0
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
20/06/11 17:15:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://master:9000/user/root/random7/dummy-split-0:0+1
20/06/11 17:15:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local203266267_0001 running in uber mode : false
20/06/11 17:15:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
20/06/11 17:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: wrote record 94600. 78409377 bytes left. > map
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: wrote record 94600. 78409377 bytes left. > map
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local203266267_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: wrote record 94600. 78409377 bytes left. > map
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local203266267_0001_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local203266267_0001_m_000000_0' to hdfs://master:9000/user/root/random7/_temporary/0/task_local203266267_0001_m_000000
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: done with 102093 records.
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local203266267_0001_m_000000_0' done.
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local203266267_0001_m_000000_0
20/06/11 17:15:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
20/06/11 17:16:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
20/06/11 17:16:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local203266267_0001 completed successfully
20/06/11 17:16:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 22
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=303475
                FILE: Number of bytes written=765149
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=1077285240
                HDFS: Number of read operations=4
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=3
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=1
                Map output records=102093
                Input split bytes=115
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=28
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=219676672
        org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomWriter$Counters
                BYTES_WRITTEN=1073754436
                RECORDS_WRITTEN=102093
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=1077285240
Job ended: Thu Jun 11 17:16:00 KST 2020
The job took 14 seconds.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053594/change-the-size-of-random-data-generation-on-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

This command documented in the source code here
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/RandomWriter.java

You can specify `mapreduce.randomwriter.totalbytes` in the xml configuration in `HADOOP_CONF`.

But more likely you want to have your own main method for this task.